# Generating pagination links

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to implement a paging system that displays nearby page numbers as well as pages at each extreme.  For example, if the user is on page 20 of 40, the following links should be displayed:  1, 2 ... 18, 19, [20], 21, 22 ... 39, 40.  The solution would be similar to the one described here:

http://90poe.com/alex-lee-on-bell-curve-pagination

I have seen code to do this in PHP, but not in ASP.net (ideally I am looking for C# code).  If anyone has done anything like this previously, it would be very helpful to see your code.

Comment: On the page you linked to, the pictures don't show up.

Comment: What would the linked pages be for page 5 of 40?

Comment: For 5 out of 40, the links would be: 1, 2, 3, 4, [5], 6, 7 ... 39, 40. (The first two are always displayed, the last two are always displayed, and the two immediately adjacent are always displayed.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code you'll need to use to generate the pagination links largely depends on what technology based on ASP.NET are you using. You'll need different code when using ASP.NET MVC, different code for Web Forms and different code for controls such as `Repeater` or `Grid`.

In any case, you'll need to generate the page numbers to show. The following code shows how to do that using LINQ and C# 3.0. We first generate all the ranges (beginning, around the current page, end) and then remove invalid pages (e.g. max+1) and make sure that each page is returned only once:

```
// Generate all three ranges
var pages = new[] { 1, 2 }.Concat(
            Enumerable.Range(current-2, 5)).Concat(
            new[] { max-1, max });

// Filter invalid pages and make sure we return each page only once
pages.Where(n => n >= 1 && n <= max).Distinct();
```

You could write this using a lots of `if`s, but it may be difficult to get all the cases right, so this may be more elegant approach. Binding it to a specific technology is probably a topic for another question, though.

Comment: Thanks.  I have access to LINQ so I am trying to use this solution, but I'm getting the following error on the line beginning "Enumerable.Range": Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<int>' to 'int[]'.

Comment: @alpheus: The type of `pages` needs to be `IEnumerable<int>` or `var` - I originally wrote `int[]`, which was wrong (I corrected the answer).

Comment: Hmmm, I don't think this works, i,e, it shows pages on the high range that don't exist.

Answer (score 1):

I second Tomas' solution.

In case you can't use LINQ, here are all those if's :

```
    private List<int> PaginationPageNumbers(int CurrentPage, int TotalPages)
    {
        int i;
        List<int> lst = new List<int>();

        if (TotalPages > 0) lst.Add(1);

        if (TotalPages > 1) lst.Add(2);

        i = CurrentPage - 2;
        if (i > 2) lst.Add(i);

        i = CurrentPage - 1;
        if (i > 2) lst.Add(i);

        if (CurrentPage > 2) lst.Add(CurrentPage);

        i = CurrentPage + 1;
        if ((i > 2) && (i <= TotalPages)) lst.Add(i);

        i = CurrentPage + 2;
        if (i <= TotalPages) lst.Add(i);

        i = TotalPages - 1;
        if (i > (CurrentPage + 2)) lst.Add(i);

        if (TotalPages > (CurrentPage + 2)) lst.Add(TotalPages);

        return lst;
    }
```